# Definition of stopping time $\sigma$-field

Tags: probability-theory

The usual definition of a stopping time $\sigma$-field goes

$$ \mathcal F_T := \{A \in \mathcal F : A \cap \{T \leq t \} \in \mathcal F_t \text{, for all } t \in \mathbb{R}_+ \}.$$

For a fixed $t$, I can see that $A \cap \{T \leq t \} \in \mathcal F_t$ whenever $A \in \mathcal F_s$ for $s \leq t$. But are there examples of "future" events that are still "observable" in conjunction with the random time $T$? That is, is there an example of $A \in \mathcal F_u$, $u > t$, yet $A \cap \{T \leq t \} \in \mathcal F_t$?

**Edit:**

Intuitively, a possible example would be an event that has to do with either a constant process, or a process stopped at $T$.

Any other types of examples?

Comment: Does $A := \{T > u\}$ satisfy your requirements?